# After reinstalling Android from stock images, why do updates complain about modified /system files?

Tags: nexus-5, stock-android, unrooting

After discovering the hard way that <s>rooting</s> <s>modifying `/system`</s> looking at `/system` the wrong way breaks updates, I've decided to drop all of the power-user stuff and just go the sanctioned route—no custom recovery system or rooting or *anything*; just pure, stock Android. To that end, I set about <s>performing a factory reset</s> [`[unrooting]`](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unrooting/info), so to speak.

These are the steps I've followed:

1. [Acquire the `platform-tools` for your computer's operating system.](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/42484/44848) Extract them and add the resulting directory to your `$PATH`.
2. [Download a stock-Android image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images), making sure that the model identifier matches that of your device, but that the version is *not* the latest (this is necessary for step 8). Verify the image using the hash included in the table, then extract it. Fire up a shell if you haven't already, and change to the extracted directory.
3. Unlock the bootloader (`fastboot oem unlock`).
4. Reinstall Android (`./flash-all.sh`). Be sure to catch the device before the last reboot by holding down the boot-to-recovery key combination as soon as the script prints `rebooting...` after writing the cache image (this saves you having to reboot again for the next step).
5. Lock the bootloader (`fastboot oem lock`).
6. Reboot. Wait for Android to…do whatever it does when you boot a new version for the first time.
7. Go through the initial device setup. (I personally connect to a Wi-Fi network, and then skip everything else to save a bit more time).
8. Check for, download, and install an Android OS update. Wait some more while that happens.
9. Observe the following on the device's screen, with the text `Error!` in white beneath it:

[image: Pictured: the Android robot on its back, with an exclamation mark inside a red triangle.]

10. Bring up the recovery menu and choose `View recovery logs`, then `/cache/recovery/last_log`. Scroll to the bottom and look for an indication of why the update failed. Transcribe the most relevant lines, along with the version and build ID of the image from step 2.

My device is a Nexus 5, purchased in November of 2013 from the Play Store. So far, I've tried this using Android 6.0.0/MRA58K and Android 5.1.1/LMY48M, which produced the following in the recovery logs:

6.0.0/MRA58K:

```
failed to stat "/cache/saved.file": No such file or directory
script aborted: "/system/priv-app/SetupWizard/oat/arm/SetupWizard.odex" has unexpected contents.
```

5.1.1/LMY48M:

```
Remounting and verifying system partition files...
script aborted: assert failed: sha1_check(read_file("/system/fonts/NotoSansTC-Regular.otf"), some_hash)
```

In both cases, the problem seems to be a file under `/system` with contents that aren't equal to the ones the update installer is expecting. This is exceptionally frustrating, given that my procedure *specifically* calls for official stock-Android images, retrieved from none other than Google's website and verified using the hashes they publish (and yes, I make sure to use TLS).

Did I miss a step? What's going wrong here? And how do I get back onto the blessed path and be once again deemed worthy to receive the long-sought-after over-the-air updates?

Comment: What was the vague error? Downloads from the Google android themselves factory images: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=en android current android SDK: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

Comment: @BoLawson The error is the linked picture of the Android mascot, with the literal text `Error!` below it. And yes, I got the image from the page you linked.

Comment: Well…okay. Any insights as to why OTA updates still aren't working?

Comment: It just happens sometimes but it could just be a corrupted download. You could check the recovery logs in recovery. It should be the last option to see what they state.  It might have the last_log within it. /cache/recovery/last_log

Comment: @BoLawson Hmmmm…two different things jump out at me: `failed to stat "/cache/saved.file": No such file or directory` and `script aborted: "/system/priv-app/SetupWizard/oat/arm/SetupWizard.odex" has unexpected contents.`.

Comment: Your still not stock flash the factory image from Google again.

Comment: @BoLawson No? What am I flashing, then, and where do I get the factory image?

Comment: Can you `adb sideload` the OTA update package in recovery? What are the OTA updates for (which version to which version)? You can search for `xxx OTA zip` on Google to get the zip file to sideload, as long as the `xxx` represents the correct corresponding OTA. It could indeed be a bad download of the OTA package itself, and this should help clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an explanation for you, but try more versions in general, and build MRA58N in particular.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why this worked. If I had to guess, I'd guess that the two images I originally tried installing from had bad `/system` files, but a mistake like that seems extraordinarily unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Reverting back to original rom requires a full format as partitions as well as their attributes are usually different on different ROMs. This will solve your problem with the advent of a possible change in the device's info such as IMEI or similar. Another setback is the reduction in memory from formatting, especially if your partitions contained a lot of user data during the format.

Suggestion: repeat your steps again, but this time make sure to mount your /system partition and format it as well, unmount it after (it should automatically unmount).

Now. Let the flashing begin...

Comment: I really don't think this is it, given that each script indicated every time I ran them that they were `erasing 'system'`, then `downloading 'system'` and `writing 'system'`.

Comment: Also…what? I've never heard of trying to format a partition _while it was mounted._ And why would I _lose_ storage space if there was a lot of user data before a format?